# How to define type of an object whose properties are going to be fetched from an array in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, casting, typeerror, typescript-typings

How to define type of an object whose properties are going to be fetched from an array in TypeScript.

In the following example, how can I define the type of lookUpMap object?

```
const arr1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
const arr2 = ["x", "y", "b"];

class Arr {
    
    private lookUpMap = {}
    
    constructor(private arr1: string[], private arr2: string[]){}    
    
    linearCompare(){
        for(let i of this.arr1){
            this.lookUpMap[i] = true
        }
        
        for(let i of this.arr2){
            if(this.lookUpMap[i]){
                return console.log(true);
            }
        }
        return console.log(false);
    }
}

const arrComp = new Arr(arr1, arr2);
arrComp.linearCompare()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward type I can think of for `lookupMap` is a dictionary-like object with a [string index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) whose properties are of type `true | undefined`:

```
  private lookUpMap: { [k: string]: true | undefined } = {}
```

This will let you write `true` to any string-valued key, as in `this.lookUpMap[i] = true`, and understand that when you read from a string-valued key, the result will either be `true` or `undefined`, as in `if (this.lookupMap[i]) {...}`.

Note that this has nothing to do with the fact that your keys are coming from arrays; `lookupMap` will allow you to index into it with any `string` whatsoever.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwQRhgXhgbQER2wGhmwCMCjgzsATbAXQG4AoUSWRBAJnS2wA9KAnpVINGzADZwIEGAEEkMAN5iYMAA4IAlgDc4UAKYxxIEAGsAqmoCycNQC4lWUw+hawAc1oOoCAK6GAHxhfMCp9ADNNMH0qGABfbkU4lRgWV19gKBAEAAoNHT1DdmQXHyj3TFpCfN0DeCQOUrcK2gBKR2TGVXEo-UQAYRAAWzVEfRz25VVVcOyYHPF9WE0YEHCYKAALTQgAOmLJrunVLZ3d4zNLGzVMTVpuH38j1U7j2YR5xeXV9dO99g4h2Oqk06xyf3OJgs1lstzaSmewIQS18CDAqXAEBAi0h7nBfn0rSYwPiiOSx2RUFR6LS2P0uJy4Tg4gghOJpM6aTYSEGI240QA7nIkDlioQAUTGOxeWpzr0BsNRsiJkA)

Comment: wondering if something like this would be possible: `const arr1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"] as const; type ArrKey = {[key in typeof arr1[number]]: true};`

Comment: You can try that but since `arr1` is outside the class and then passed into properties of the class, you'd need the class to be generic to keep track of this... and then looking up an element of `arr2` will be annoying since it won't be known to be a key of `lookupMap`.